# How to get fscanf to scan the next Line in C

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

The text file is a list of words similar to this. each world is on a new line

When i run my code, the only thing being printed is "hi".... how do i get it to continue to read the next lines

- hi
- hello
- welcome

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    char data[100];
    // OPENS THE FILE
    FILE *fp = fopen("/classes/cs3304/cs330432/Programs/StringerTest/people.txt", "r");
    
    if (fp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Unable to open the file\n");
    } else {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", data);
        
        printf("%s", data);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (fscanf(fp, "%s", data) == 1)`

Comment: do i still need to keep the else statement?

Comment: While you don't abandon ship in the `if` statement (`exit(1);` for example), you need to keep the `else`.  Note that you should report errors to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  It's also a good idea to include the name of the file in the error message, which means you need to create a variable that points at the file name so you can use the variable in both the call to `fopen()` and the error message.

Comment: im not following, what do you mean i dont abandon ship on the if statement?

Comment: Ask yourself - what does the `if` statement check for? Once you have worked that out then you may be able to answer whether the `else` is still needed. That is, what could go wrong if `fscanf` was called regardless of the result of the `if` check?

Comment: it is to check if the file opens properly, right ?

Comment: I mean that if your program continues after the body of the `if` statement is executed, then you have major problems.  "Abandoning ship" in context means "exit the program unilaterally", as the suggestion "`exit(1);` for example" is supposed to make clear.  I guess it depends on whether you've come across the `exit()` family of functions before, but now is a good time to become familiar with them.  (If you write `if (fp == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` then you could omit the `else` and the braces around the block of code.)

Comment: Yes, it is to check if the open succeeded or not. So if there is no `else` it means that the `fscanf` would use the file regardless of whether the file open worked or not. Which is not a good thing right?

Comment: You can use `while(fscanf(fp, "%99s%*[^\n]%*c", data) == 1) { ... }` to read the first whitespace-delimited string (of no more than 99 characters) from each line.

Comment: @dxiv There is a quirk in that `fscanf` that you need to be aware of (and you may already know). If the input consists of a string followed immediately by the newline character, the `%99s` conversion will read everything up to the newline, then the `%*[^\n]` conversion **will fail**, and the `%*c` conversion will **not** be attempted. The result is that the newline is not consumed.

Comment: @user3386109 Right, thanks, that was careless. It takes two steps, either `while(fscanf(fp, "%99s%*[^\n]", data) == 1 && fscanf(fp, "%*1[\n]")) { ... }` or separate `fgets` + `sscanf`.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get fscanf to scan the next Line in C

Read the documentation of [fscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). You cannot scan lines with it. And `fscanf` can fail, and you should handle its failure.

A possible approach is to read the next line using [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) (or [getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), or [readline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)) and later to parse it using [sscanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html).

Be also aware that in 2021, [UTF-8 is used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org). So document on paper what your program should do if your `people.txt` file contains a line like `Être ou ne pas être` or a line with `СТАРЫНКЕВИЧ` (in Cyrillic letters).

If allowed, use a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (asking for all warnings and debug info), improve your code to get no warnings, and then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program.  You could install [Debian](https://debian.org/) on your laptop to get `gcc` and `gdb`

The documentation of your program could use [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation to specify what are the valid inputs.

Consider generating parts of your C code with tools like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).

When [fopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) fails you could use [perror](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to report the error.

You may want to read the wikipage about [recursive descent parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

You may want to study -for inspiration- the source code of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).